# Asynchronous Streaming in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, streaming, async-await

I am working with Streaming with WCF and I have a question about what the paragraph on "[Enabling Asynchronous Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#collapseableSection11)" means from the MSDN article on Large Data and Streaming in WCF.

> To enable asynchronous streaming, add the
>   `DispatcherSynchronizationBehavior` endpoint behavior to the service
>   host and set its `AsynchronousSendEnabled` property to `true`. We have
>   also added the capability of true asynchronous streaming on the send
>   side. This improves scalability of the service in scenarios where it
>   is streaming messages to multiple clients some of which are slow in
>   reading possibly due to network congestion or are not reading at all.
>   In these scenarios we now do not block individual threads on the
>   service per client. This ensures that the service is able to process
>   many more clients thereby improving the scalability of the service.

I understand that the above means I add

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AsyncStreaming">
      <dispatcherSynchronization asynchronousSendEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  ...
```

To my `web.config` file and referencing the `AsyncStreaming` behavior in my endpoint, however I don't understand what doing those steps accomplishes for me. Do I need to modify my code at all to take advantage of this asynchronousness?

Also on a similar topic (but if it is too different I will move it to a new question), how does using async/await effect using Streams in WCF? Can I do `Task<Stream> Foo()` in my service contract? I make some database calls whose results I eventually wrap in to a custom stream that I will be returning from the WCF service. Being able to use things like `ExecuteDataReaderAsync()` is very useful, can I still use it when dealing with streamed instead of buffered messages?

I have tested it and I know it "works" using Tasks but I don't know if doing it causes the function to fall back to "Buffered" mode like when you provide more than one parameter to the function (See the 3rd paragraph of "[Programming Model for Streamed Transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#collapseableSection12)" on the same MSDN page) and I don't know how to check to see if that is happening.

Comment: Hi Scott!  I have *exactly* the same doubt regarding Task wrapped results. Were you able to confirm if their use causes the channel to revert to "buffered" mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced it down to [`RequestContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.requestcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via the .NET Reference Source. Apparently, the [`ChannelHandler.sendAsynchronously`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/ChannelHandler.cs#f7deb121e20b1fe9#references) field controls whether the message reply is done asynchronously (via `RequestContext.BeginReply/EndReply` APM methods) or synchronously via `RequestContext.Reply`.

As far as I can tell, all this does is frees a server-side thread which is returned to the pool, and which otherwise would be busy inside `RequestContext.Reply` with "pumping" the stream to the client, for as long as the `Stream` object is alive on the server.

This appears to be totally transparent, so I think you can safely use `async` TAP-based contract methods and return `Task<Stream>`. In another contract method you could do `await Stream.WriteAsync`, for example.

Please share your actual experience as your own answer when you get there, I'd be very interested in the details :)

Comment: Do I HAVE to use "await" statements for the runtime to release the thread?

Answer (score 2):

Good question on a complex topic. I've implemented a streaming WCF service to accommodate huge (up to 2GB) downloads, but I'm a bit confused, too, about this AsyncStreaming=True business since WCF is already asynchronous (in that each connected client gets its own thread and requests and receives asynchronously) as long as

```
 <ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)>
```

But you do have to alter your code to make streaming work. Even if you have **Binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed** , the program will revert to buffering if you don't change the code so that your uploading and downloading functions A) get and return streams and B) your upload and download functions implements something like this:

```
//oBuffer is your content
if (oBuffer != null) {
    oStream = new MemoryStream(oBuffer);

    if (oStream.CanSeek) {
        oStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
    return oStream;
}
```

This is a decent HowTo article I used as a guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Comment: For your 2nd part, I meant do I have to make any changes to my code to go from `asyncStreaming=false` to `asyncStreaming=true`, I did not mean changes to my code to support `TransferMode.Streaming`, that change was done a long time ago.

Comment: I didn't use asyncStreaming=True, or =False, and yet the program works asychronously. Yes, you have to change Transfermode to Streaming, but you also need to change the code so you're returning a Stream and that it can seek. What that does is allow the client (which must be setup in similar fashion) to request the next part of the stream. It took a while to get my head wrapped around this, but think of WCF streaming like a File object.

Comment: When you write a program to read a large file, the program won't wait until the entire File is read before returning the bytes to the program. Rather, it reads (some) and outputs to the bytes as it goes (i.e. asynchronously). The WCF works the same way, that's why it's useful for big data transfers. It starts reading, but before all the bytes are read, it's already sending the bytes it has out to the client. After the client the first set of bytes, the client will contact the host (under the covers, you don't have to program it) to get the next set of bytes.

Comment: Thus the client program effectly takes over control of the process, requesting more bytes until all the data is received. Follow?